# How to Snyc to the Time of a Website using Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have written a Python Script to open a specific website that allows me to submit a forum post at a very specific time (ex: 1:00 pm). However I think there is a delay between my computer time and the server time. Is there a way to find the time of a website (server?) down to the microsec so I can sync it to my computer?

What I have done:
In my code I set the desired Hour to 13 and Minute to 00 and Microseconds to 20000 (which is 0.02 sec). When I ran my script and submitted the forum I noticed the time submitted on the website is 12:59. And so I have been changing the microseconds from 0.02 sec to 0.25 sec in order to account for time delay between server and local computer. After 5 try I am able to hit the 1 pm time with 0.25 sec. However I feel like there is a better way of dealing with this.

I am brand new to Python (came from a MATLAB background). CHEERS!!!

Comment: It is not expected that a web server is in the same timezone of your local computer. And you cannot really know if a remote server is using the same time server (NTP) as your machine. And on a slow network connection, HTTP requests could easily take seconds.

Comment: There's no standard way to get the time of another machine (there's a `TIME` protocol, but most machines don't enable it these days). On the modern Internet we expect all machines to synchronize their clocks with standard time sources, so there shouldn't be much clock skew.

Comment: Are you able to get the NTP server time?

Comment: @Barmar Maybe I can sync to a "standard" time source. Is there a benchmark standard time source that most websites use? I apologize in advance if this is a dumb question... I am not a programmer

Comment: This is the default in most computers these days, you shouldn't have to do anything. On Macs, you check the "Set time automatically" box on the Date and Time settings, for instance.

Comment: @Barmar,  I think my local computer time and website time is off since my submit button line of code only runs when my website time is at 13:00:20000

Comment: If this is a forum, you can download a page from the forum that specifies the post time for a post and how many minutes ago the post was made. From that data you can infer what time the server is set to, within a minute. You can probably narrow it down to within a few seconds by posting something and then checking to see at what exact time it says your post happened 1 or 2 minutes ago.

Comment: Go to https://time.is/ to check if your computer's time is correct.